# How to use static files in the Django code, but not in the template?

Tags: python, django

*Hi there*,
on my Django 4.0 project, I'm implementing a profanity filter validator.
So I have a `file.txt` with a list of profanity words.
I put that file in my `static folder` and now need to use it in my validators.py code.
But **how to import it to the code not in the template** for usage?
I think it's a bit tricky.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

for solving this, you should follow these **steps**

#### Step 1:

In your setting file, define this variable  "STATIC_URL", like this :

`STATIC_URL = 'static/'`

#### Step 2:

Then add another variable by name "STATICFILES_DIRS" in your setting file,like:

**where is your static Files**

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/', # you can dont add this
]

STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"`

#### Step 3:

you should add static address in URL file that you find it with exactly this name "urls.py", like :

**you could set Static File Address**

`from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

#### Step 4:

then in your template files, for loading static files, you need add these code lines :

`{% load static %}
{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}`

good Lucky!

Comment: I know how to use static in templates. I wanna use it in another code as I mentioned in validators.py, i.e. not in templates, but in code - views, validators, etc.

Comment: you can open it with python I/O code  in your validators.py file, why you want to use txt file in static files?

Comment: But where to store it? just in the app dir near other modules?

Comment: you can user this:

`from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`